# Create posts inside CPT post

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions

In CPT Each post host multiple posts and access them with custom URL.

Custom post type: serial

Create posts with serial title: abc, xyz, etc

Now This is what I need to create, Inside every serial (abc,xyz) I want to create posts.

Then Access theme with custom URLs

Access all serials: http://localhost/serial/

Access serial with title: http://localhost/serial/abc/

Access Episodes: http://localhost/serial/abc/episode-1 & http://localhost/serial/abc/episode-2 & http://localhost/serial/abc/episode-3

Is this possibe with wordprss?

Please guide me any soultion & recommendation will be accept. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to work as above . You need to follow below points to make it work :

1. Make custom post type name Serials.
2. Add new custom taxonomy name serial which will be showing name of the serials
3. Now add each episode as the post and assign the taxonomy serial name to it.

Let me know if this clears your above question.

Comment: Every serial have episode-1. Then how can i create multiple post with same URL. Because episode-1 is part of every serial

Comment: I think you can add it as it will have different category you will not face the issue of same links Still I would recommend you to use title as "{serialname}- Episode1"

Comment: Please accept the answer if you feel it is usefull to you